# Comprehension Lists

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have three different lists named `L1`, `L2` and `L3`.  I am supposed to create a list of inner lists where each inner list is `[x,y,z]`. `x,y,z` are elements from  `L1`, `L2` and `L3` respectively and they fulfill the conditions:

```
x > y, and  x > z and y > 2*z
```

For example:

```
L1,L2,L3 = [8,11,12,13],[1,5,9],[4,8,10]
```

The output should be:

```
[[11, 9, 4], [12, 9, 4], … ]
```

I tried:

```
L1,L2,L3 = [[8,11,12,13], [1,5,9], [4,8,10]]
listush2 = [[r[0],r[1],r[2]] for r in L1,L2,L3 if r[0]>r[1] and r[0]>r[2] and r[1]>2*r[2]]
```

but I get only:

```
>>> listush2
[]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would suggest breaking this down into why it fails. For instance, take the `if` conditionals, and move the values they compute into the returned result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at your `for` loop.

The question implies that you have to check triples of elements where each element of this triple is an element of one list. You aren't iterating over the individual elements.

At least have one loop per list that iterates over each element in a list - so you'll have **three** loops all together - then you can check for the condition stated in your question.

Something like this should work:

```
listush2 = [[x,y,z] for x in L1 for y in L2 for z in L3 if x > y and x > z and y > 2*z]
```

Notice how this list comprehension correctly iterates over each possible triple of elements where each value of the triple comes from one list.  For each possible triple, check the condition stated in your question then add this triple of values as an inner list in the overall output list should the condition be evaluated to `True`.

Running in IPython:

```
In [7]: L1,L2,L3 = [8,11,12,13],[1,5,9],[4,8,10]

In [8]: listush2 = [[x,y,z] for x in L1 for y in L2 for z in L3 if x > y and x > z and y > 2*z]

In [9]: listush2
Out[9]: [[11, 9, 4], [12, 9, 4], [13, 9, 4]]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate it (:

Comment: @NettaKasher You are very welcome.  Once and only if you are satisfied and no longer need help, consider accepting either my answer or newtover's answer.  See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Thought the answer from @rayryeng is probably what is expected, the resulting list comprehension is not readable. As he has noted, the problem is that you are iterating over lists instead of elements of each list. But what you expected is called a product of lists and has a separate function in `itertools` module:

```
In [44]: from itertools import product

In [45]: [[r[0],r[1],r[2]] for r in product(L1,L2,L3) if r[0]>r[1] and r[0]>r[2] and r[1]>2*r[2]]
Out[45]: [[11, 9, 4], [12, 9, 4], [13, 9, 4]]
```

Or better:

```
In [46]: [[x, y, z] for x, y, z in product(L1,L2,L3) if x>y and x>z and y>2*z]
Out[46]: [[11, 9, 4], [12, 9, 4], [13, 9, 4]]
```

Comment: This is definitely more readable. +1. I wrote the answer with the mindset that the OP probably hasn't covered the `itertools` module yet.